# Car dealership stock orders list

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, normalization

I work for a big car dealership in Switzerland. We receive daily a list of cars in our car parks located all around the country. This list serves us to find which car our clients are looking for, so that we can propose them an offer.

The list is huge and difficult to work with. For instance all optional and model versions are written all in one cell. So, I had the idea to build a database, with a research form and a report in MS Access so that we just need to load this list in an excel sheet, run a formatting macro in order to have a proper list to work with, then feed it to the database through table connection. This will definitely save us a lot of time

So, at the end of the formatting macro my list look kinda like this:

[image: formatted car list]

Since the same optionals on different cars have different prices, I need to have my data to look like this:

[image: target table format]

so that in my report I can do  a table join query and have a list of the car's optionals with their prices. Is there a way to do a "Table Normalisation" in MS Access?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the number of the option column is limited  you could try using a select  union for get all the result in single column

```
insert into OPTTrans (carID, BrandId, Model, OPT)
select carID, BrandId, Model, Opt1
from OPT
where Opt1 is not null
union  
select carID, BrandId, Model, Opt2 
from OPT
where Opt2 is not null
union
select carID, BrandId, Model, Opt3 
from OPT
where Opt3 is not null
order by carId
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't know in advance how many optional a car has. In my excel sheet i left the space for 40 OPTs columns.

Comment: then   you could work in two way 1) or you build a query with 40 union  .. 2 ) or you using a procedural programming language  .. read the not normalized  table and insert the values you need  in a normalize  table  (with a schema equivalent to your result)

Comment: I just tried your solution and it works as i imagined. The only thing that i need now is when the OPTX columns don't contain values, that they don't get "considered". Do you know how to do it?

Comment: You can filter the value for optx is not null

Comment: In the end it doesn't really matter if i have null values. Since i have 40 OPT to unite, it takes almost 5 minutes in order to have the result of the query. Do you happen to have a trick to make it go faster? I want also to insert the result in a new table, since i need to do the query once every day. I tried to use the INSERT INTO operator, but i keep getting syntax error on the secon FROM. Is there something I have to do in order to have the 40 UNION operations working with the INSERT INTO operator?

Comment: for performance there are not useful suggestion  .. you are doing a full select for the table  (if the null values are not important the table is full scanned ..  each time  )   anyway i have update the answer  with insert into table too  ..

Comment: INSERT INTO OPTTrans (OrderNr, Brand, Model, ModelName, Optional)
SELECT
OrderNr, Brand, Model, ModelName, OPT1 AS Optional
FROM OPT
WHERE OPT1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT
OrderNr, Brand, Model, ModelName, OPT2 AS Optional
FROM OPT
WHERE OPT2 IS NOT NULL

Comment: Im still getting the syntax error when i add the INSERT INTO statement. Any idea?

Comment: tehre was a missing comma in column sequence in insert clause  .. and be  sure there is a space between table name and () for insert into tablename  (...)  .. . have update the answer  with a code for the first 3 select  union  .. let me know

Comment: I resolved by adding an extra step. First a Tempqry with the unions and then one with a insert into statement.